# Using a C# 7 tuple in an ASP.NET Core Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tuples, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-7.0

Do you know why this works:

```
public struct UserNameAndPassword
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
}


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]UserNameAndPassword usernameAndPassword)
{
    Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword);
    if (this.AuthenticationService.IsValidUserAndPasswordCombination(usernameAndPassword.username, usernameAndPassword.password))
        return new ObjectResult(GenerateToken(usernameAndPassword.username));
    return BadRequest();
}
```

But when I replace it with a tuple, this doesn’t work?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody](string username, string password) usernameAndPassword) //encrypt password?
{
    Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword);
    if (this.AuthenticationService.IsValidUserAndPasswordCombination(usernameAndPassword.username, usernameAndPassword.password))
        return new ObjectResult(GenerateToken(usernameAndPassword.username));
    return BadRequest();
}
```

`usernameAndPassword.username` and `.password` are both null.

Are you not allowed to use tuples in a controller?

Comment: Pretty sure tuples aren't going to work like that unless you write a custom model binder. Why would you want this anyway, it's far less readable? Make a proper class or just have two parameters.

Comment: As far as using a proper class, this is what tuples are partly designed to do - reduce the need for throw away classes that clutter stuff up.

Comment: But these aren't throwaway classes, and the code looks worse in this context. As a return type for a method it looks far more readable, but not so much as a parameter.

Comment: I can use multiple params, which is what I was originally doing, but I was wondering what is preventing me from doing what was in the original question.  But looks like that won't be possible.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Comment: MVC may bind these parameters if you name the input elements that submit to this action properly. `name="usernameAndPassword.username"`, `name="usernameAndPassword.password"` for example.

Comment: If it ever works then I hope they will credit you as the inventor of TVC - "Tuple-View-Controller" ;-)

Comment: I agree with @DavidG. The flaw here is in looking at these classes as "throw-aways". The classes you bind to create a contract and self-document how your actions work. They are anything but "throw-away".

Comment: Can't you only have one FromBody param? The tuple thing would be kinda nice for having multiple params in the body without making a class for them. It would be a nice in-between for query params and a full-fledged body object.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It doesn't work because named tuple names are not quite "real", it's mostly syntax sugar provided by compiler. If you look at `ValueTuple` set of types, by which named tuples are represented, you will see that they have properties like `Item1`, `Item2` and so on.

Compiler will rewrite all your references to named tuple names to their real names (`Item1` etc). For example you have this:

```
static void Create((string username, string password) usernameAndPassword) {
    Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword.username);
    Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword.password);
}
```

But when you compile that, what you really will have is this:

```
static void Create([TupleElementNames(new string[] {"username", "password"})] ValueTuple<string, string> usernameAndPassword)
{
  Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword.Item1);
  Console.WriteLine(usernameAndPassword.Item2);
}
```

Your names are now only in metadata attribute `TupleElementNames`, but not in code.

For that reason, when you post something like:

```
{"username": "x", "password": "y"}
```

to your action, asp.net cannot bind. But if you would post:

```
{"item1": "x", "item2": "y"}
```

then it will bind with no problems. You can write custom binder probably, which can use `TupleElementNames` attribute, but there is no reason to really. Just use separate parameters or real model as suggested in comments. Your action input parameters is not some throwaway thing. You might later want to validate them, generate documentation from the model and so on.

Comment: You saved my day..!! Well explained. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 16):

You can use [this](https://github.com/m6t/M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder/blob/master/README.md) package. This package binds json body to your models.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/m6t/M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder/blob/master/README.md)

### Installation

```
//Nuget
Install-Package M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder -Version 1.0.0

//dotnet cli
dotnet add package M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder --version 1.0.0
```

## Usage

Modify startup.cs like

```
using M6T.Core.TupleModelBinder;
....

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc(options =>
  {
      options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TupleModelBinderProvider());
  });
}
```

Post request body

```
{
  "user" : {
    "Name":"Test",
    "Surname":"Test2",
    "Email":"example@example.com"
  },
  "someData" : "If you like it, you put a data on it"
}
```

And in your controller use it like

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateUser((User user, string someData) request)
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        var newUser = db.Users.Add(request.user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { userId = request.user.Id, someData = request.someData});
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one. Though not fully implemented. Issue I have found so far, no support for swagger, supports post method only, no tuple return, no support for json convertors