# API call with named tuple as input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, namedtuple

One of my API endpoints expects a object containing a list of named tuples. An example of the input object would be:

```
public enum Countries { Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra /*...*/ }

public class InputModel 
{
    public List<(Countries Country, bool Visited)> CountriesVisited { get; set; }
}
```

When I load up the Swagger, the example input value does *not* use the named tuples, but rather `item1` and `item2`. For example:

```
"countriesVisited": [
    {
        "item1": "Afghanistan",
        "item2": "false"
    }
]
```

And when I call the endpoint, it seems that I have to use `item1` and `item2` for it to recognise that values have been specified. Using the named tuple (`country` and `visited`) results in the specified values being ignored.

Is it possible to change this so when I call the endpoint, I can use the named tuple names, instead of the generic names `item1` and `item2`?

I know I could work around this by creating a class with `Country` and `Visited` as properties, however I'd like to avoid creating a custom class for such a thing, if possible.

Comment: I think not. See here (https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2017/04/csharp-7-valuetuple-types-and-their-limitations) for an explanation and a JSON example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named tuples are a syntactical sugar, so what you are seeing is expected.

More here: [Using a C# 7 tuple in an ASP.NET Core Web API Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005989/using-a-c-sharp-7-tuple-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api-controller)