# Updating multiple inputs to their objects

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can update my database for single object with tag helpers or Html.BeginForm but I want to do it on one page. Therefore if I click the button every input's raw should trigger POST method.

[image]

I will set every player's goals and assists then click the save button. My expectation is 5 goals and 2 assists should save for Messi in my database. Then 1 goal and 2 assists for Modric etc. I thought that if I use a loop inside or maybe outside I can make it but it didn't work. How can I reach my target?

***View***

```
@model (Team home, Team away, List<Player> playerList, Player playerTest)
<form asp-controller="MatchDetail" asp-action="EditMatch" method="post">
    @foreach (var item in Model.home.Players)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.PlayerID" />
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <div class="col">
                <label asp-for="@item.Name">@item.Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Goals" type="number" min="0" max="100" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input type="number" asp-for="@item.Assists" type="number" min="0" max="100" />
            </div>

        </div>
    }
    <div class="col">
        <button class="button btn-danger" type="submit">SAVE</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I also tried this part with for loop but it didn't work.

***Controller***

```
public class MatchDetailController : Controller
{
    MatchManager matchManager = new MatchManager(new EfMatchDal());
    TeamManager teamManager = new TeamManager(new EfTeamDal());
    private readonly AppDBContext _context;
    
    public MatchDetailController(AppDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditMatch(int id)
    {
        var match = matchManager.TGetByID(id);
        var homeTeam = match.HomeTeam;
        var awayTeam = match.AwayTeam;
        Team home = new Team();
        Team away = new Team();
        List<Player> playerTest = new List<Player>();
        Player playerSingleTest = new Player();
        List<Team> TeamList = _context.Teams.Select(x => new Team()
        {
            Name = x.Name,
            Draw = x.Draw,
            GoalDifference = x.GoalDifference,
            GoalsAgainst = x.GoalsAgainst,
            GoalsFor = x.GoalsFor,
            Initial = x.Initial,
            Logo = x.Logo,
            Lose = x.Lose,
            PlayedMatches = x.PlayedMatches,
            Players = x.Players,
            Points = x.Points,
            TeamID = x.TeamID,
            Win = x.Win
        }).ToList();
        foreach(var item in TeamList)
        {
            if (item.Name == homeTeam) home = item;
            else if (item.Name == awayTeam) away = item;
        }
    
        playerTest = home.Players;
    
        //Tuple Test
    
        (Team, Team, List<Player>, Player) tuple = (home, away, playerTest, playerSingleTest);
        //Team teamHome = _context.Teams.Select(x => new Team() 
        //{ 
        //    Name = homeTeam,
        //});
        return View(tuple);
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditMatch(Player player)
    {
        // TODO
        return RedirectToAction("EditMatch",2);
 }
```

player parameter always returns null.

I guess tuple limited my actions. I know it's not a well-written code but if you suggest a solution for my purpose I'd be happy.

Comment: As you may know tuple names are not quite "real", it's mostly syntax sugar provided by compiler. You would require to use your custom class for your scenario. You could [`check this thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005989/using-a-c-sharp-7-tuple-in-an-asp-net-core-web-api-controller).

Answer (score 0):

Cannot write the entire code for you here, but I can give you an idea on how can we achieve this.

1. Send all the data from Angular to Web Api. Once you are sure if all
   the data is being sent, then majority of the work in in Web Api.

   [{ "playerName": "Messi", "goals": "5", "assists": "3" }, {
   "playerName": "Ronaldo", "goals": "5", "assists": "3" }, {
   "playerName": "Neymar", "goals": "5", "assists": "3" }]
2. Now you have receiving the data of (Player Name, Goals and Assists),
   mostly it will be a list/json array of each player and its
   associated data.
3. Now you can run a foreach loop and update/insert all the data in the
   table.